# How to send and receive Objects through SocketChannel in NIO

Tags: java

I am trying to transfer image file through socketchannel but it doesn't read at server side. what should i do?

Comment: Why would an image file be sent as a serialized `Object`?  Wouldn't you just want the raw bytes?

Comment: Your question is out of scope for SO as you provide no details on which anybody could base an answer.  Please read the [faq] and [ask] to understand the guidelines for posting on SO.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer your image as byte stream.

```
InputStream input=new FileInputStream("image.png");
byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
int readData;
while((readData=input.read(buffer))!=-1){
socketOutput.write(buffer,0,readData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have here you can only conclude.

- The problem needs a greater understanding of what is going wrong.
- You have a bug in your program you need to fix e.g. use a debugger.
- You have a misconfiguration. Check your sender and receiver can connect/talk to one another and there is no firewall in the way.

Comment: thanx for suggestion. actually i am bulding chatting application using NIO and i want to transfer documents from one user to another

Comment: So when you create a simple test where one thread is sending and one is receiving what happens?